# Getting error while creating datasets based on CIFAR10 dataset class

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I need to create 2 datasets with one dataset having classes from 0 to 4 and other having classes from 5 to 9 of `CIFAR10` datasets but I'm getting this error: `"boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1; dimension is 32 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1"`

Here's what I have tried so far

```
  import keras
  from keras.datasets import cifar10
  (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
  print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
  x_train shape: (50000, 32, 32, 3)
  Getting error at this point
  x_train = x_train[y_train < 5]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing out y_train.shape gives (50000, 1). To properly index the first dimension of x_train with y_train, you have to strip the second dimension.

```
x_train = x_train[y_train[:, 0] < 5]
```

the `[:, 0]` notation means return all elements along the first dimension, but only the first element along the second dimension.

`x_train.shape` now gives (25000, 32, 32, 3).